# How to run a ClickOnce application (.appref-ms) on a remote computer?

Tags: c#, .net, wmi, clickonce, remote-access

I am trying to launch a ClickOnce application via an .appref-ms shortcut on a remote machine using WMI, but cannot succeed. The below code works fine if I try to run notepad.exe.

```
ManagementPath pm = new ManagementPath(@"\\server\root\cimv2:Win32_process");
ManagementClass processClass = new ManagementClass(pm);

//Get an input parameters object for this method
ManagementBaseObject inParams = processClass.GetMethodParameters("Create");

//Fill in input parameter values
inParams["CommandLine"] = @"C:\Documents and Settings\Start Menu\Programs\New\New App.appref-ms";

//Execute the method
ManagementBaseObject outParams = processClass.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams, null);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try launching the .appref-ms shortcut via `rundll32`:

```
inParams["CommandLine"] = @"rundll32.exe dfshim.dll,ShOpenVerbShortcut ""C:\New App.appref-ms"";
```

Alternatively, instead of relying on the shortcut path, you could use the application deployment URL (you can see it by opening the .appref-ms file in a text editor):

```
inParams["CommandLine"] = @"rundll32.exe dfshim.dll,ShOpenVerbApplication http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application";
```

Keep in mind that `Win32_Process.Create` cannot create *interactive* processes remotely.

Comment: Here's a link with additional information in case anyone is as unfortunate as I am to have to use ClickOnce in the new decade:
https://www.mking.net/blog/programmatically-launching-clickonce-applications

Answer (score 0):

What is the error that you are getting.

BTW, there seem to be two problems with the commandline path that you are using.

1. Start Menu folder IMO is in C:\Documents and Settings\"Usernamehere"\StartMenu.
2. I am not sure but I think that you can't run a program remotely which lies inside a user's profile. Try installing the program to some other location like your c:\program files and then try to call it.

Apart from that, if you mention the exact error you are getting, then it would be helpful to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Hi Amir

For point 1 there is username i just removed it from the code. 
Now i have put the  New App.appref-ms in C: dive but still not able to launch it. I get the error code "8" which means "Unknown failure" using the below code
ManagementBaseObject outParams = processClass.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams, null);
Console.WriteLine("process returned: " + outParams["returnValue"]);